# cannot apply operator - to 'double','android.widget.EditText'

Tags: java, android, operator-keyword

I'm new in the android world :)
I've read an Android Tutorial and I attempt to use it. 
I wanna try to calculate the renal function,
I've used some EditText with NumberDecimal Type to get three values:
age, weight, creat
and then I've used a Radiogroup to select a value which depends of gender,
but when I wanna try to get the result,
I get the error

> "Operator '-' cannot be applied to 'double','android.widget.EditText'

I don't understand the cause of the error.

```
public class CG extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RadioGroup ChoixSexe = null;
    private double ChoixValeur=0;
    private double Calcul=0;
    private double age=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cg);
        EditText poids=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.poids);
        EditText age=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.age);
        EditText créat=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.créat);
       ChoixSexe =(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.sexe);
        ChoixSexe.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int LeChoix){
                switch (LeChoix)
                {
                    case R.id.homme:
                        ChoixValeur =1.23;
                        break;
                    case R.id.femme:
                        ChoixValeur=1.04;
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
        Calcul=(140.0-age)/créat*poids*ChoixValeur;
    }
}
```

Apologies for my English which is a bit approximate.

Comment: `age` is an `EditText` reference. What do you think should happen when you subtract an `EditText` from a `double`?

Comment: Well i told in my EditText, that then InputType must be DecimalNumber, i thought it was enough :) Thanks anyway

Comment: As noted, the `age` variable is an object.  You must convert the value stored in the object to a number before you use it in math.  Do not convert it to a double.  age is never a double.  Know what value type will be entered (perhaps an integer) and convert it to the correct type.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the EditText objects to doubles (or int, float, long, etc.) to use standard math operators.

Answer (score 0):

this here:

```
 Calcul=(140.0-age)/créat*poids*ChoixValeur;
```

is not compiling because age is an object of the class `EditText`,

get the text(that will be a sstring) calling the method `age.getText()`, then **parse** that to Double so you can do math operations with it

## Example: (validate first that age is a valid input)

```
double d = Double.parseDouble(age.getText().toString());
calcul = (140.0 - d) / creat * poids * ChoixValeur;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Double.valueOf (age.getText ().toString ())and be sure you have rnumerical value in that text field